# Conditional Clause in Where Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking to add a conditional IIf or CASE to a WHERE clause in Access SQL to add an either/or condition based upon a passed value. I've seen a couple of examples on the site, but they were a little different and I have struggled to get the code to work in my case. The code:

```
SELECT * FROM incHC 
WHERE 
incHC.repdte=(SELECT Max(repdte) AS maxDt FROM bYrs) AND 
incHC.asset>0 AND 
incHC.eq2<>0 AND 

(
CASE WHEN recType="inst" THEN 
  incHC.orphan=0
ELSE
  incHC.orphan<=1
END
)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If this is MSACCESS SQL, and you're dealing with a single column of output, then what you need is an [IIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php).  If you put your IIF in one of your output columns, you can use it as a conditional value for the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something with your query, you should be able to do this without a `CASE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM incHC 
WHERE incHC.repdte=(SELECT Max(repdte) AS maxDt FROM bYrs) 
    AND incHC.asset>0 
    AND incHC.eq2<>0 
    AND
    (
        (
            recType="inst" 
            AND incHC.orphan=0
        )
        OR
        (
            recType<>"inst"
            AND incHC.orphan<=1
        )
    )
```